# Mysterious overfull \hbox

Tags: sectioning, warnings

I want each section title to be underlined, with the section number on the right. Furthermore I want to use `parskip`. This is what I did to get that:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{name=\section}[block]{\normalfont\Large}{}{0pt}{\makebox[\textwidth]{#1 \hfill \thesection}}[\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

However, now I get an error:

```
Overfull \hbox (30.0pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 9--9
|[]|
```

I turned on `\usepackage{showframe}`, but visually everything is within the borders.

How can I fix this, or hide the warning?

Comment: Please provide a complete small document that shows the problem, not just fragments.

Comment: Add a `%` after the final braces in lines 2 and 4.

Comment: @egreg that would be a start but 30pt sounds a lot for two word spaces, which is why I was asking for an example:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, of course.

Comment: If I try the code I get `Overfull \hbox (3.1333pt too wide)` which is to be expected because of the two spaces. The 30pt is quite large and can't be explained only by your code snippet.

Comment: I am working on a short self-contained example, give me a minute. One thing I would like to note is that in the original document the entire `\titleformat` definition was on one line.

Comment: @egreg It seems the culprit is in `parskip`. This is a self-contained example: https://gist.github.com/nightcracker/7388787 I have no idea how to fix it though - without parskip my document looks awful.

Comment: Please put an example _in this question_ parskip would have been my initial guess, in which case  `\noindent\makebox...` (and the `%`) is probably what you want

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok, I edited the question with the exact problem distilled and distractions removed. `\noindent` doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: I noticed that if you remove the `[parfill]` option, the overfull box is removed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The parts of the heading are internally paragraphs and so you need to reset `\parfillskip` to allow them to reach the right hand edge.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}



\titleformat{name=\section}[block]{\parfillskip0pt\normalfont\Large}{}{0pt}{{#1 \hfill \thesection}}[\vspace{1ex}\titlerule]

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}

X\dotfill X
\end{document}
```